# Как правильно сверстать данную карточку товара?

Tags: html, css

[image: каротчка товара]

Не могу понять как сверстать эту карточку товара, понимаю что бейдж и рейтинг нужно ставить на абсолют, но вот как сделать заголовок, статус товара и цены без понятия

Comment: Вы не можете понять или хотите, чтобы за Вас всё сделали?) Хотя бы попытку какую-то приведите

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Answer (score 1):

Полностью верстку за вас делать никто не будет (кроме фрилансеров). Тут вам помогут советом. Когда вы создаете вопрос вы должны помнить о том, что он должен быть уникальным настолько, насколько это возможно, а так же помнить о том, что вы пополняете базу знаний своим вопросом и его должно быть просто найти. Поэтому используйте ключевые слова вашей проблемы.

По вопросу. Вы можете использовать `grid` для построения карточки товара. Или же используйте `bootstrap` там много готовых решений.

Если бы я делал такую карточку, я бы начал с такого скелета. Вы все верно говорите, вы можете использовать `absolute` для того чтобы развесить декоративные элементы (новинка, скидка и.т.д)

```css
.container {  
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 8px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1.1fr 1.1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1.1fr 1.1fr;
  gap: 0px 0px;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  grid-template-areas:
    "img title"
    "img price";
}

.img { 
  grid-area: img; 
}

.title { 
  grid-area: title; 
}

.price { grid-area: price; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="img">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/130x200">
  </div>
  <div class="title">
    <h2>Название</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="price">
    <p>Цена, рейтинг, статус</p>
  </div>
</div>
```